# Get Lock screen Wallpaper android

Tags: java, android, lockscreen, wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I want to get the current wallpaper drawables of both lockScreen & homescreen but i can't figure out how to get LockScreen Wallpaper.

I have used this Code to get HomeScreen Wallpaper Drawable & its Working Fine

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

And for LockScreen drawable,

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getBuiltInDrawable(WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
```

this Returns Null Drawable Value...

Is there any other way to get Current LockScreen Wallpaper !

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967444/9613462